# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting this exception when I try to convert my object to JSON using Jackson.

I have a pretty simple interface

```
public interface Spreadsheet {

    ExcelSheet getSheetName();
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Civ.class, name="civ"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=GreatPerson.class, name="greatperson"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Wonder.class, name="wonder")
})
public interface Item<T> extends Spreadsheet {

//some methods
}

@JsonTypeName("civ")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "objectType")
public class Civ implements Item<Civ> {

//Implementation
}
```

Then a class using Items

```
public class PBF {
    private String id;

    private List<Player> players = Lists.newArrayList();
    private List<Item> items = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

When I try to create a JSON using this code, I get the exception defined in the title

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pbf);
```

---

**The entire source code is on Github. If you want to reproduce, just clone the repo, and run `mvn clean install && mvn exec:java then point your browser to localhost:8080/games**

PS: Required Java 8 and MongoDB

[Source code from Github](https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame-randomizer/tree/master)

Comment: Can you post a full example? I don't get the exception when using the code you've provided with missing code filled (assumptions).

Comment: The items in PBF has lots of items. That might have something to do with it?

Comment: That's most likely it. I have no tried it. An object has a reference to itself.

Comment: By full example, what do you mean? There are many more implementations of Item which I have. Its basically a normal POJO. No magic

Comment: A full example would be a complete example we can run word for word and reproduce the exception you got.

Comment: The code is on github. https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame-randomizer/blob/TryingWithoutJacksonMapper/civilization/src/main/java/no/asgari/civilization/resource/GameResource.java

Comment: I have edited the question and added how you can clone and run the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I had to remove the  from the interface.

So now it looks like this

```
public interface Item extends SpreadSheet {
}

public class Civ implements Item {
}
```

The problem was that I had the same object in for instance Civ class in the type.

I don't think I need the type anyways, so I am good